# adding custom navigation bar in viewwillappear makes navigation slow?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have created a custom navigation bar.Now i am adding this into `viewwillappear` method.Due to this when i return to my view controller it takes time to load.

```
  func addViewToNav()
  {
    myView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.width)!-40, height: (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.height)!))

    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 5, y: (myView?.frame.size.height)!/2-14, width: 28, height: 28)
    let image = UIImage(named: "download")
    imageView.contentMode=UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
    imageView.image=image
    imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width/2
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    imageView.backgroundColor=UIColor.yellow
    label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: imageView.frame.size.width+15, y: 0, width: 150, height:  (myView?.frame.size.height)!))
    label?.text="Label"
    label?.textColor=UIColor.white
    myView?.addSubview(imageView)
    myView?.addSubview(label!)
    self.navigationController?.view.addSubview(myView!)
    //add tap gesturte on imageview & label
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tapBlurButton(_:)))
    myView?.isUserInteractionEnabled=true
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired=1
    myView?.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
  }
```

Please guide how can i make it fast because this is very slow.

Comment: check image size maybe its too large

Answer (score 0):

It is taking time because every time the controller appears on the screen `viewWillAppear` will be called and each time the code for creating the custom view, adding it as the subview and then adding gesture recognizer will be executed.

There are 2 ways that might reduce the processing time:

1. If you want to do it programatically, the add the code to create and add custom navigation bar in `viewDidLoad` instead of `viewWillAppear`
2. Add the custom navigation bar in the `storyboard` itself and create an outlet connection for it in the controller.